# HTACCESS url rewrite pronblem

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php?L=IT [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ elenco.php?L=IT&url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^en/index.html$ index.php?L=EN [L]

If I call www.test.com/en/index.html the rewrite dont work as i want. It call elenco.php ...?? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your rules around.

```
RewriteRule ^en/index.html$ index.php?L=EN [L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php?L=IT [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ elenco.php?L=IT&url=$1 [L]
```

The elenco rule is getting executed before the en/index.html rule and your `[L]` parameter is preventing it from getting there.